# theme_image_style() doesn't output what is expected

Tags: theming, media, uri

I have a module that doesn't seems to work correctly, so I dived into its code, and there is something that I don't understand:

The module does something like this: (I replaced the 'path' key with an hardcoded value to show the problem)

```
$params = array(
    'style_name' => $presetname,
    //'path' => $image_url,
    'path' => "public://images/image.jpg",
    'attributes' => $attributes,
    );
```

Then $param is sent to the theme_image_style() hook

```
$img = theme('image_style', $params);
```

The problem is that if i dump the output of theme_image_style():

```
dpm( $img);
```

then i get

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://mysite.local/sites/default/files/styles//public/images/image.jpg?itok=qZxUAGIS" alt="" data-thmr="thmr_99 thmr_100" />
```

In **admin/config/media/file-system**, my public path is set as: *sites/default/files*

I should have:

```
src="http://mysite.local/sites/default/files/images/image.jpg
```

instead of:

```
src="http://mysite.local/sites/default/files/styles//public/images/image.jpg
```

Why does the theme function add 'styles//public' and where could I remove this?

Thanx in advance for your help

Comment: If you don't want a styled version of the image, don't use `theme_image_style`, - use `theme_image` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Drupal 7` provide `Image style` functionality which allow administrator to set predefined size and can apply `image style` to any image in site.

> Using image styles you can scale, crop, resize, rotate and desaturate
>   images without affecting the original image. By default three sizes
>   are defined: 'thumbnail,' 'medium', and 'large'. The thumbnail style,
>   for example, is shown with the teaser for image posts and when
>   browsing image galleries.

In your code, you have defined `$img = theme('image_style', $params);` which mean that you are applying `image style` to your image.

When we apply `image style` to any image, it will create a new `image` in `styles/[stylename]/public` directory and does not affect the `original` image source.

There is no `stylename` in your `http://mysite.local/sites/default/files/styles//public/images/image.jpg` url after `style` part of url, so I guess `$presetname` is not properly defined in your code.

You can try below exammple:

```
$params = array(
    'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
    //'path' => $image_url,
    'path' => "public://images/image.jpg",
    'attributes' => $attributes,
    );
$img = theme('image_style', $params);
```

Comment: Thanx jayendra,

I added a style to my picture, and it works now!  :)